# How to do setState on empty object inside state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am having a state somewhat like this

```
this.state={
  angles:{}
}
```

So how can I do setState on this empty object. For instance if I want to set a key and value inside my empty angles. How can I do that. ( Likewise I want 0:90 inside my `this.state.anlges`.
After setting the state it should look like

```
this.state={
   angles:{0:90}
}
```

Thanks in advance. Need to pass both the 0 and 90 as variables.

Comment: `const modified_state = {...this.state};
modified_state.angles = {0:90};
this.setState(modified_state);`

Comment: @MaxSvid I need to pass both 0 and 90 as variables. Any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd do it by setting a new `angles` object, like this if you want to completely replace it:

```
this.setState({angles: {0: 90}});
```

or like this if you want to preserve any other properties and just replace the `0` property:

```
// Callback form (often best)
this.setState(({angles}) => ({angles: {...angles, 0: 90}}));
```

or

```
// Using the current state (often okay, but not if there may be other state updates pending)
this.setState({angles: {...this.state.angles, 0: 90}});
```

---

In a comment you've asked:

> Actually I need to pass 0 and 90 as variables. For instance consider 0 as one variable and 90 as one variable. Then in that case How can i do that?

In the above where I have `0: 90` you can use computed property notation: `[propertyname]: propertyvalue` where `propertyname` is the variable containing the property name and `propertyvalue` is the variable containing the property value. For instance, here's that last example with those variables:

```
this.setState({angles: {...this.state.angles, [propertyname]: propertyvalue}});
```

Comment: Actually I need to pass 0 and 90 as variables. For instance consider 0 as one variable and 90 as one variable. Then in that case How can i do that?

Comment: @classydraught - In the above where I have `0: 90` you can use computed property notation: `[propertyname]: propertyvalue` where `propertyname` is the variable containing the property name and `propertyvalue` is the variable containing the property value.

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this:

```
this.setState((currentState) => ({
  angles: {
    ...currentState.angles,
    0: 90,
  }
}));
```

be aware that number as key in objects is not recommended

if both 0 and 90 are values then `angles` should be an array containing duos of values.

example:

```
angles: [[0,90], [60,45], [0, 45]]
```

to do this within your state you would to something like this:

```
// initial state:
this.state = {
  angles: [],
}

// add a value:
this.setState(({angles}) => ({ 
  angles: angles.concat([[0,90]])
}))
```

note the double array syntax in concat, it is necessary. Without this you would end up with a flat 1 dimension array

Comment: `setState` supports partial updates, there's no reason to do the `...currentState` part of that.

Comment: @Apolo How can I pass 0 and 90 as two different variables?

Comment: @classydraught I've added a way to deal with this in my answer

Comment: @Apolo Actually using duos I am losing data I want something to be fetched using the first value i.e `0` in this case. That can be done by doing `this.state.angles[0]` , but using duos I can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest way to do it:

```
this.setState({angles: {0:99}});
```

Answer (score -2):

You probably want something like this:

```js
const state = {
    angles: {}
};

const setThisToState = { 0: 90 };
const key = Object.keys(setThisToState).toString();
const value = Object.values(setThisToState).toString();

state.angels = { [key]: value }; // { angles: { '0': '90' }
```

**EDIT:**

Since you asked for having 0 and 90 in variables, I wanted to point out the computed property notation.

```
class YourClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      angles: {}
    }
  }

  componendDidMount() {
  // using object destructuring here
  const { angles } = this.state;

  // say you are fetching data from an API here
  fetch(fromAPI)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => { // say data.coordinates = { 0: 90 }
      const key = Object.keys(data.coordinates).toString();
      const value = Object.values(data.coordinates).toString();

      // this overrides current state.angles. To keep values of state.angles use 
      // the spread operator as mentioned below
      this.setState({ angles: { [key]: value }})

      // spread out current state.angles if you wanna keep the values + add a 
      // "new object"
      this.setState({ angles: ...angles, [key]: value})
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: updating state directly is not how you update a component in React.
Also, using Array.prototype.toString to compute key and value is not a good idea

Comment: @Apolo exactly!

Comment: I agree, was a bit lazy on the react part. I will edit my answer. But whats the problem with Array.prototype.toString method? I just wanted to point out the computed property notation as @classydraught was asking for 0 and 90 inside variables.

Comment: the issue with array to string is that you will endup with ',' characters in your key if you happen to have more than one entry in your array. From what I can see you want the first item of the keys' array, not the string representation of the array itself. Same for values